# SharePoint doesn't really provide a mechanism for moving content between libraries / sites

Tags: sharepoint, move

I want to move a page between sites from a site collection.
I am getting result as :-

Operation Failed.
Access Denied. Not enough permission.

When I login as Site administrator, I can move page between sites.

The user with contribute permission cannot move pages between sites.

Please help me for this issue...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the permission level issue.
Instead using the default permission levels (Contributor in your case, which has no rights to manage web), you should probably create a custom permission level that has permissions fits your need.
Please go read
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA101001491033.aspx

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

James is correct, you need more permissions.

If you don´t wan´t to add those permissions to the users you could create your own "move" function that uses elevated permissions to do the copying. Things to look out for though is that you would have to "restore" the current users credentials on the createdby and modifiedby columns after the move since those will be sharepoint\system when elevated.